Cannot select another option for variable in GitLab runner
Background: I create job in .gitlab-ci.yml but I Cannot select another option for variables for my job. My job is run by Powershell.
Description of source code:
.gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:
  - maintenance
  - build
  - signing
  - test
variables:  
  TESTING_WITH_VPF:
  value: "1"
  options:
  - "1"
  - "0"
  description: "Use VPF, set 1" 
  SELECTED_MODULE:
  value: "a"
  options:
  - "a"
  - "b"
  - "c"
  description: "Specify the module to run tests on (e.g., a)"   
*...some of code...*
job_modules_testing:
  tags:
    - board_xxxx
  stage: test
  variables: 
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  script:
    - echo "Starting testing job"
    - echo $env:SELECTED_MODULE
    - echo "Environment Variables:"
    - env
    - powershell -File $env:Test_file
*...some of code...*

Issue: After triggering job in Gitlab Gui (in browser) with SELECTED_MODULE = b. My job cannot run with SELECTED_MODULE = b. It runs with default value SELECTED_MODULE = a.
(Images are attached below)
Dear All,
I hope you will give me a solution or point out the error to fix when handling this issue
Best Regards,
Ben Ng.
enter image description here

Is the indenting in this code snippet exactly the same as you have it in your .gitlab-ci.yaml file?

Hi Dillon Brock,

Hi Dillon Brock,
I confirm with you that the code snippet is the same as the one in my .gitlab-ci.yaml. In "variables," I have some variables with fixed values, and it runs okay. I have some issues similar to mine at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29159. It was created 5 years ago.
